# Facebook and google plus login gives white screen after login

Tags: android, facebook, webview, google-plus

I am using facebook and google plus login in my application. After I log in from facebook or google, I get a blank screen. I have added overriding url approach. After that whenever I get that white screen, I am redirected to my desired page. Which is good. But the login action does not successfully achieved. As I am not getting any contact from it or whatever I need after login, I can't achieve that. Any idea, Thanks..

Here is my code...

```
if(url_new.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth") ||     url_new.startsWith("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"))
                {
                    String redirectUrl =     "http://www.mypage.com";
                    view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a bad redirect URI configured in your API project. Because you are signing in the user from Android, you should be redirecting the user back to your application.

You should also not be using a Web View to sign the user in. The reasons for this are described in this article, [In-app browsers considered harmful](http://furbo.org/2014/09/24/in-app-browsers-considered-harmful/).

The solution is to use native sign-in for your supported provides.

For Google+ you should be [signing the user in using the Google+ API][https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in] as demoed in [the Google+ Android quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android).

For Facebook, you should be using [the Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started).